# Jquery Datepicker won't update with selected date

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

In the input area of my Jquery Datepicker it displays this "MM/DD/YYYY". Whenever I select a date from the calendar, the "MM/DD/YYYY" does not change, but it should. Is this something I need to set manually, or is it supposed to happen on its own?

This is how everything is set up currently:

```
 $("#dateInput").datepicker({ 
                minDate: today, 
                maxDate: validto, 
                onSelect: getDateCheck
            });

 function getDateCheck(dateText, inst){
            /* update settings */
            ParentLetter.callbackUrl = "/modulecallback/ParentLetter.aspx/Update";
            ParentLetter.callbackData = '{ appDeadlineStr: "' + dateText + '"}';
            $('#dateInput').datepicker( "setDate", dateText );

            /* get! */
            ParentLetter.Get(); 
}
```

Comment: Did you close your getDateCheck function? - missing curly brace at the end

Comment: Ah yes, - it does get closed, I just didn't copy that bit. I can edit.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was instantiating it as type="date", but it should have been type="text". Bummer it has to be done that way though. Not very semantic.